# Can't create a migration in asp.net core EntityFrameworkCore.core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Method 'Create' in type 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.MySQLSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitorFactory' from assembly 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=8.0.22.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' does not have an implementation.
it gives me this error

```
namespace DBStuff
{
    public class MessageDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }

        public MessageDBContext(DbContextOptions<MessageDBContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Message>().ToTable("Messages");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Message>().HasKey(u => u.ID).HasName("PK_Messages");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Message>().HasIndex(p => p.Name).IsUnique().HasDatabaseName("Idx_Name");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Message>().Property(ug => ug.ID).HasColumnType("int").IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Message>().Property(ug => ug.Name).HasColumnType("nvarchar(50)").IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Message>().Property(ug => ug.Email).HasColumnType("nvarchar(50)").IsRequired(false);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Message>().Property(ug => ug.TelephoneNumber).HasColumnType("int").IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Message>().Property(ug => ug._message).HasColumnType("nvarchar(200)").IsRequired();


        }
    }
}
```

Message Class:

```
namespace DBStuff
{
    public class Message
    {

        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }


        [MaxLength(25)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(15)]
        public int TelephoneNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(150)]
        public string _message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Startup.CS

```
namespace Somafix
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            //services.AddEntityFrameworkMySQL();
            services.AddDbContext<MessageDBContext>(options => options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
namespace Somafix.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly MessageDBContext _context;



        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, MessageDBContext context)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Catalog()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult AboutUs()
        {
            return View();
        }



        //[HttpGet]
        //public IList<Message> Get()
        //{
        //    return (this._context.Messages.ToList());
        //}





        public IActionResult ContactUs()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should try [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql). Oracle's provider can be outdated and unstable.

Comment: Your target project 'Somafix' doesn't match your migrations assembly 'DBStuff'. Either change your target project or change your migrations assembly.
Change your migrations assembly by using DbContextOptionsBuilder. E.g. options.UseSqlServer(connection, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Somafix")). By default, the migrations assembly is the assembly containing the DbContext.
Change your target project to the migrations project by using the Package Manager Console's Default project drop-down list, or by executing "dotnet ef" from the directory containing the migrations project.

Comment: now this error ahah

Comment: my database is empty

Comment: SOLVED aaa :D yees

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED GUYS YEAH!

so I changed the Nuget package . I was using mysql.data.entityframeworkcore and now I'm using pomelo.entityframeworkcore.mysql.
I wrote in startup class this

services.AddDbContext(options => options.UseMySql(connectionString,ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString), b=> b.MigrationsAssembly("Somafix")));
where Somafix is my asp mvc project , where the startup class is situated